# Is there a programmatic way to retrieve data from Google Code?

Tags: google-code, google-data-protocol

Is there Google Data Protocol for [Google Code](http://code.google.com/)? I want a programmatic way to retrieve data (such as *My favorites* of an user, project information, etc.) from it.

I saw on the [API Directory](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html) that Google Data Protocol currently does not have Google Code (besides Issue Tracker API) yet. If so, are there other approaches to retrieve those data?

Thank you.